# Cover Image link to my website

Tags: facebook, web, hyperlink, photo, cover

I want make it so that when you click on my cover image on my personal facebook page you get directed to my website instead of my fb photo gallery.

This is what I have done....

-Right clicked image
-Inspected element
-right clicked what the fb address i wanted to change
-Edit HTML 
-added my website in the place of facebook's.

This worked, however it only worked with one click of the photo. After that it went back to the default facebook address in my photo gallery. My question is there anyway to change it permanently?

Thank you,

Brandon

Answer (score 2):

> is there anyway to change it permanently?

No.

There are [a few](http://userscripts.org/) [tools](http://www.kynetx.com/) that you could use to automate what you did manually; injecting some Javascript into the page to modify the `href` attribute of that link. However, this is not a general solution and you would be the only one to see the effects, since Facebook doesn't see the change you made and other users won't have your script.

On the other hand, if you can find a way to inject javascript into a comment or post on your profile, you would be able to modify the link for anyone viewing your profile. Since this ability is a well known [security issue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), which Facebook protects itself against, your chances of success are slim.

Answer (score 0):

you can't change source code from a site you don't own, what you did with your browser worked just that time but after refreshing it's all gone because source code is downloaded again. Javascript works only on client side so you can't make permanent changes.

Take a look on [this](http://www.motive.co.nz/glossary/client-server.php)

Answer (score 0):

You can generate more sophisticated content than an image from your album.

Use opengraph:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="The Rock"/>
<meta property="og:type" content="movie"/>
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/"/>
<meta property="og:image" content="http://ia.media-imdb.com/rock.jpg"/>
<meta property="og:site_name" content="IMDb"/>
<meta property="fb:admins" content="USER_ID"/>
<meta property="og:description"
          content="A group of U.S. Marines, under command of
                   a renegade general, take over Alcatraz and
                   threaten San Francisco Bay with biological
                   weapons."/>
```

Like the relevant page, done. Your timeline will be nicer, and you don't need to hack.

More info about OpenGraph: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraphprotocol/